# yii text field validtaion with ckeditor

Tags: php, yii

I have a text field in which I have used CKEditor:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'text'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'text', array('id'=>'editor1')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'text'); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Rules in model is

```
public function rules()
{
 return array(
    array('text', 'required'),
  array('text', 'validateWordLength')
);
}


public function validateWordLength($attribute,$params)
{
    $total_words= str_word_count($this->text);
    if($total_words>4000)
    {
       $this->addError('text', 'Your description length is exceeded');
    }
    if($total_words<5)
    {
       $this->addError('text', 'Your description length is too small');
    } 
}
```

This works fine

1) when I leave field blank I get required text error.

2) when I write words less them 5 or more than 4000 I get desired error

but when I insert some blank space then I am not getting any error and form is submitted.

Comment: Try with $total_words= str_word_count(trim($this->text));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to remove multipe Whitespaces in your function

```
public function validateWordLength($attribute,$params)
{
    $this->text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$this->text); 
    $total_words= str_word_count($this->text);
    if($total_words>4000)
    {
       $this->addError('text', 'Your description length is exceeded');
    }
    if($total_words<5)
    {
       $this->addError('text', 'Your description length is too small');
    } 
}
```